# Convert between NHWC and NCHW in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

What is the best way to convert a tensor from NHWC format to NCHW format, and vice versa?

Is there an op specifically that does this, or will I need to use some combination of the split/concat type operations?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

All you need to do is a permutation of the dimensions from NHWC to NCHW (or the contrary).

The meaning of each letter might help understand:

- **N**: number of images in the batch
- **H**: height of the image
- **W**: width of the image
- **C**: number of channels of the image (ex: 3 for RGB, 1 for grayscale...)

---

#### From NHWC to NCHW

The image shape is `(N, H, W, C)` and we want the output to have shape `(N, C, H, W)`. Therefore we need to apply `tf.transpose` with a well chosen permutation `perm`.

> The returned tensor's dimension `i` will correspond to the input dimension `perm[i]`

```py
perm[0] = 0  # output dimension 0 will be 'N', which was dimension 0 in the input
perm[1] = 3  # output dimension 1 will be 'C', which was dimension 3 in the input
perm[2] = 1  # output dimension 2 will be 'H', which was dimension 1 in the input
perm[3] = 2  # output dimension 3 will be 'W', which was dimension 2 in the input
```

In practice:

```py
images_nhwc = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 200, 300, 3])  # input batch
out = tf.transpose(images_nhwc, [0, 3, 1, 2])
print(out.get_shape())  # the shape of out is [None, 3, 200, 300]
```

---

#### From NCHW to NHWC

The image shape is `(N, C, H, W)` and we want the output to have shape `(N, H, W, C)`. Therefore we need to apply `tf.transpose` with a well chosen permutation `perm`.

> The returned tensor's dimension `i` will correspond to the input dimension `perm[i]`

```py
perm[0] = 0  # output dimension 0 will be 'N', which was dimension 0 in the input
perm[1] = 2  # output dimension 1 will be 'H', which was dimension 2 in the input
perm[2] = 3  # output dimension 2 will be 'W', which was dimension 3 in the input
perm[3] = 1  # output dimension 3 will be 'C', which was dimension 1 in the input
```

In practice:

```py
images_nchw = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3, 200, 300])  # input batch
out = tf.transpose(images_nchw, [0, 2, 3, 1])
print(out.get_shape())  # the shape of out is [None, 200, 300, 3]
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness: an explication why these commands are needed would be supportive

Comment: @user3085931 : you got it

Comment: Also, what is `perm` - or how is it defined?

Comment: `perm` is the permutation of the dimensions of the image to go from `(N, H, W, C)` to `(N, C, H, W)` for instance.

Comment: where did you use `x` and `perm`?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot is x == images_nchw ?

Answer (score 0):

To convert 'NCHW' to 'NHWC'

```
from keras import backend
backend.set_image_data_format('channels_last') #channels_first for NCHW
```

Comment: This does not do any conversion, it only changes how Keras interprets data.

Comment: Idd, deceptive answer of Rishi. This parameter pertains for example to `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img`. When you have a 128x128 RGB image, then `load_img` returns an array of shape (3,128,128) with `'channels_first'`. `load_img` returns an array of shape (128,128,3) with `'channels_last'`.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest TF2 models, we have a functionality in tf2onnx package. tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(input_as_nchw = [List]) is the latest function update which can be used while converting the model from .pb format to .onnx
also it successfully converts the NHWC to NCHW.
https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx/blob/e896723e410a59a600d1a73657f9965a3cbf2c3b/tf2onnx/convert.py#L408