# Tensorflow, CNN: Do I have to make convolutional neural network with 'NCHW' format when using GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I reviewed DQN implementation code (https://github.com/devsisters/DQN-tensorflow) and found out this code generate `CNN` network with `NCHW` format when using `GPU`, `NHWC` otherwise.

I wonder whether this is mendatory... I mean, is it ok to generate `CNN` network with `NHWC` format even if I used GPU?

Answer (score 0):

It might be ok if you don't care much about performance. In general, on GPU, NCHW is faster.

Why do you want specifically use NHWC on GPU ? 
You can convert between them, see
[Convert between NHWC and NCHW in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689423/convert-between-nhwc-and-nchw-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Yes, I mean speed.