# Converting channel last to channel first image

Tags: tensorflow, face-recognition, image-preprocessing

I have an image tensor of the following dimensions

```
TensorShape([Dimension(1), Dimension(96), Dimension(96), Dimension(3)])
```

I want this tensor to be in following  channel first dimension

```
TensorShape([Dimension(1), Dimension(2), Dimension(96), Dimension(96)])
```

I have tried

```
tf.transpose (image, perm = [0,3,1,2])
```

but it did not work It is returning in the same as previous.

Since, this is the requirement of Facenet algorithm , please suggest the way to do it.

Comment: You can't just reshape, this will return invalid values. E.g. if your input was [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], there is a big difference between transposing ([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]) and simple reshaping ([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]). However I suspect that OP isn't using transpose correctly since it should be doing the job. Please provide a more complete code sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert between NHWC and NCHW in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689423/convert-between-nhwc-and-nchw-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the tensor into NumPy array and then use np.rollaxis and convert back to Tensorflow tensor.